# Why $ C_{00}$ is not complete with respect to $\sup$ norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

If $$C_{00}:=\{ x=\{x_n\} \in \mathbb{R^\mathbb{N}}: x_n=0, \forall n>k \text{depending on }x\}$$Can you help me to give such a cauchy sequence in $x$ such that does not converge to $C_{00}$.

Comment: What about $x^{(k)}=(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots,1/k,0,\ldots)$? One step further: prove that $\overline{C_{00}}=C_0$, the set of sequences which tend to $0$.

Comment: @julien thanks to you for your hints

Comment: You're welcome. You can write an answer if you want, you know?

Answer (score 1):

To prove $\bar C_{00}=C_{0}$

Let $x\in C_0$. Let us choose $\epsilon >0. $Then by definition there exist $k \in  \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq k$ $|x_n| <\epsilon$. Now consider $y=\{y_n\}$ by $y_n=x_n$ for $n<k$ and otherwise zero. Then $\|y-x\|_\infty<\epsilon$.